# How do I pass a variable to into HttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I want to give the request.onload function a variable, and add the request.response into that variable. How do I do that?

```
function loadathing(url, target){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        target = request.response;
    };
}
```

This doesn't work because it forgets what target is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. First, in order to pass the response to `target`, you would need to do it on a property of target rather than target directly since target can't be a native value (native values such as strings and numbers cannot be passed by reference).

```
function loadathing(url, target){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        target.response = request.response;
    };
}
var target = {};
loadathing('foo.php', target);
```

Secondly, since you are performing an asynchronous ajax request, you will need to add a callback to your function so that the outer code knows when `target.response` is populated.

```
function loadathing(url, target, cb){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        target.response = request.response;
        cb();
    };
}
var target = {};
loadathing('foo.php', target, function () {
    console.log(target.response);
});
```

You can then simplify it by removing target all together and using the callback.

```
function loadathing(url, cb){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
        cb(request.response);
    };
}
loadathing('foo.php', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I have a number of objects, and I want to use a simple function call to request information and then add it into an object of my choosing. That's what the target was for. Anyway thanks, I never really understood what callbacks are, but now I do. That worked.